# How to debug CSS in Android native browser?

Tags: android, css, remote-debugging, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm building an hybrid app with Cordova for Android.
The HTML5/CSS3 is rendered properly with Chrome for desktop and Chrome for Android.

However, through Cordova, the HTML5/CSS3 is rendered with the native browser (the application named "Internet"). And it seems there are a few troubles with the CSS interpretation.

Firefox has Firebug, and Chrome has a developer panel, available on desktop for remote debugging. Do you know any similar tool I could use in order to debug the CSS efficiently  the mobile native browser?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I finally found **Weinre**.
This solution belongs to the Cordova project.
http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/

Comment: Last release in GitHub of Weinre is **from Oct'2014**.

I posted how to use **Chrome's Developer Tools Window** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678239/how-to-debug-css-in-android-native-browser/40569745#40569745)

Answer (score 13):

I've tried weinre on Android 2.2 stock browser and it is working nicely

To set up it,

```
sudo npm install -g weinre

// make it available to external (than just localhost)
weinre --boundHost -all-

// include this line (change to your IP address) to every page to be tested
<script src="http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>
```

More details from this website [Remote debugging with weinre](http://www.broken-links.com/2013/06/28/remote-debugging-with-weinre/)

Comment: Plus one for providing steps.

Answer (score 3):

Just to give a more recent option.

You can use BrowserSync too. Currently it has Weinre already integrated to this.

```
# Using a local.dev vhost
$ browser-sync start --proxy

# Using a local.dev vhost with PORT
$ browser-sync start --proxy local.dev:8001

# Using a localhost address
$ browser-sync start --proxy localhost:8001

# Using a localhost address in a sub-dir
$ browser-sync start --proxy localhost:8080/site1
```

http://www.browsersync.io/docs/command-line/

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I run my Android Virtual Device console with `$ android avd` and start my configured Android v4.4.2 Emulation only with **native Browser** installed.

Next, I run my Chrome v54.0 for Desktop in my laptop, open Google-Developer-Tools/*Top-Right-Contextual-Menu*/More-Tools/**Remote-Devices**...

There, I see my Virtual Device in *connected* state, so I can click in **Inspect** button of any Page of my Ionic2 App.

This action, opens a new **Chrome's Developer Tools floating window** where I can inspect CSS, HTML and Javascript in the same way I do in my Web applications.

Hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Get Started with Remote Debugging Android Devices

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be asked elsewhere, but maybe not with as specific a question. Regardless, I have found this answer ([Is there a kind of Firebug or JavaScript console debug for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981329/is-there-a-kind-of-firebug-or-javascript-console-debug-for-android/32733441#comment54812640_32733441)) to be helpful, but instead of using Cordova, in combination with my comment, using [Xamarin Android Player](https://xamarin.com/android-player).

Answer (score -3):

use console JavaScript API  [click here for more information](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html)

Comment: This ressource deals with JS console. I would be mostly interested by the CSS status: which styles are applied to specific DOM elements...

Comment: You can also use Chrome for Android Remote Debugging [check out this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_7Wyj6DciY)

Comment: I'm afraid this is working with Chrome, and not the native browser. This solution was also quoted in the original question.