# Debugging an Android WebView from the PC via adb

Tags: android, debugging, webview, adb

I have just recently started android development. I'm actually building a Web application that runs off an Android WebView. So, I'd like to know if there is any way to debug the web application (js,css,html) from the PC via the ADB or anything. I Googled it and got options but none have an extensive debugging facility like firebug. So, any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start here: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a kind of firebug or javascript console debug for android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981329/is-there-a-kind-of-firebug-or-javascript-console-debug-for-android)

Answer (score 1):

Since Android 4.2 (if i'm not mistaking the version) you can:

1. turn on development mode on your phone
2. connect it via USB cable to your PC
3. make sure to "Trust this computer" on the tablet/phone
4. go to `chrome://inspect` on your PC in Google Chrome, you should see your device and the pages that are open on it.
5. clicking one of the links will pop up an inspector for the respective page on the device, complete with inspect element, console, networking and everything else the Chrome inspector has.

This is how i debug my app on a Nexus 7 tablet. If your device is running an older version of Android, there's little you can do apart from `console.log`'s and tediously finding them through an `adb logcat`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that feature requires Android 4.4 or newer, as per the documentation (linked below) for debugging WebViews. Prior to 4.4, you could still debug Chrome browser pages using the Chome App, but not WebViews as they did not use Chrome until 4.4.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews