# How can I extract the first paragraph of web page contents in a WKWebView

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

In a WKWebView, if I need webpage's title,I can get it via `webView.title`.

But when the first paragraph of webpage's contents is needed,there is no easy solution. Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you control the HTML then you could use a [query selector](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) like:

```
document.querySelector("#content").innerText.split("\n")[0]
```

Note: You can inject javascript similar to this answer: [Get HTML from WKWebview in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751860/get-html-from-wkwebview-in-swift/34759075#34759075)