# Tabbed browser - single wkwebview

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I wanted to Create a simple tabbed browser app like Firefox, chrome with single wkwebview in swift.
 Is that possible with single wkwebview or I need to use multiple webviews. In case of single web view how to load urls when switch between tabs. I meant how to save the last state of the webpage before switching tabs as any normal browser does.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Then it will be easier to help out.

Comment: I believe you're best off devoting a webview to each tab. But it's not a requirement. It depends on whether you want to handle everything or let some things handle themselves.

Comment: Thanks @Mozahler. My actual need is different which redirected me to this question. This is my requirement. Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/44076743/4919630. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Any suggestion for this?

Comment: @ShaliniPadu have you got any luck