# String contentsOf doesn't load same content as it is displayed with a browser

Tags: ios, swift

All I do is simply:

```
let html = try String(contentsOf: hereMyUrl)
```

but the content of html is not the same as it displayed with a browser. Why? I cannot find some tags with specific attributes. I suppose it is loaded later with js. But how to accomplish that with Swift?

However when I try to it with WKWebView:

```
        let wk = WKWebView()
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: hereMyUrl)!)
        wk.load(request)
        wk.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString()") { html, error in
            print("++++++===")
            print(html)
            print("++++++===")
        }
```

I get `nil` there. Why?

Comment: You should never use `String(contentsOf: URL)` method to download data asynchronously

Comment: And your web view is a fake, as it is not in the view hierarchy and has no size. What is your actual goal here? It looks like what you _really_ want is to scrape a page. Use URLSession.

Comment: All I need is to get content from the page. I search the content by tag. How do I use urlsession?

Answer (score 2):

You just see your html content with that method. Not Javascript or any other scripts which runs as a program on the html and can change the content during the life cycle of the web page.

Comment: I am trying to do this with WKWebView but got nil. Why?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to use WKWebView in this way. There are bunch of better ideas in getting content from WKWebView. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751860/get-html-from-wkwebview-in-swift) as an example. WKWebView has a lot of more control on the process of getting data and you can use it, instead of getting contents yourself.

Comment: above doesnt work from the question you shared. I did it as it is in my question. And it doesnt work...